# Git, como mover um arquivo de uma pasta para outra juntamente com seu histórico?

Tags: git

Estou movendo um arquivo de uma pasta para outra com o **git mv** porém o arquivo não esta vindo com o histórico, como faço para resolver isso ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O arquivo não perde o histórico quando o movemos de um diretório para outro dentro do mesmo repositório, usando o **git log** você verá o histórico dele de acordo com o diretório atual, mas se dar um **git log --follow** você verá o histórico completo.